# Trouble using PDF417-phonegap plugin for my Barcode Scanning Application

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner, pdf417, microblink

I am trying to create an application that reads information from a Driving license and gives the result based on that. I am using Ionic framework for my app and have integrated the PDF417- phonegap plugin by MicroBlink with my app.
I followed all the instructions given at: 
https://github.com/skifaster/pdf417-phonegap/blob/29cc6d8/README.md

The app is now successfully reading information from barcode and displaying it in an alert box on my screen. But I cannot find where the alert box is being generated from.

I need to know where the scan result is stored so that I can process the information further. 
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

as first, I would suggest using [original MicroBlink repository](https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap) instead of forked one. Using original repository guarantees having latest features and updates.

Next, [here](https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap/blob/master/index.js#L86) you have an example how scan is performed from javascript and how data is returned in JS callback. The example implementation raises alert with returned data.

Comment: I realized that the above repository is a sample app for the plugin and the alert box was generated by the sample itself. But when I add the same code in my new app after integrating the plugin and the scanner is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "scanner is not working"? Does camera start? Which recognition settings are you using? Which device are you using?

Comment: the camera does not start. And when i try to scan it gives me the following error message.                                                                      Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined(anonymous function)

Comment: Now I am getting an alert saying Invalid License Key! Please check ADB log for more details. I have tried running the app with null License Key as well as the key given by MicroBlink. @DoDo

Comment: I finally managed to get the app working by simply using cordova instead of ionic. Can you please tell me how can I access the date of birth in date format? @DoDo

Comment: @SaurabhShetty, dates scanned from MRZ are returned as strings in format YYMMDD.